# Is there an alternative to turnScreenOn() that acutally wakes the screen?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

The following tag, to turn the screen on, is currently deprecated:

```
tizen.power.turnScreenOn();
```

However, with this function, I was able to wake the screen after it has been turned off by, for example, a palm gesture. As there is no way to disable the palm gesture temporarily, I added this line in a screen off listener, which works perfectly, but I'm getting deprecation warnings. The following alternative:

```
tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL");
```

does, in fact, keep the screen from turning off automatically, but doesn't actually wake it if it does turn off.

Is there a function which isn't deprecated, but does, in fact, wake the screen again?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable the palm-cover event of the device. This is the system capability to allow user to disable a screen. I think that holding the screen on even though user's explicit order to turn it off (with the palm gesture) is not very good idea. Battery drain could be high with the screen constantly enabled.

*turnScreenOn/Off* methods were used in older Tizen API versions because of lack of background support, to ensure the application execution. Currently apps could work also in background, maybe this would be enough for your scenario (refer to [background-support property](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/configuring-your-app/configuration-editor#mw_setting)).

Comment: I'm aware of the background-support property, but as far as I know, although the possibility is there, background support is **not** guaranteed in Tizen Web. Although I appreciate your effort to answer my question, it isn't really an answer to the question if there is a way to wake the screen after is was turned off.